# Выгрузка из assembly

Tags: c#

Подскажите как ВЫГРУЗИТЬ dll из assembly

Comment: Конкретизируйте ваш вопрос, что вы подразумеваете под "Выгрузить" и  "assembly"?

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov - чтобы dll не было в списке assembly и код с нее не выполнялся - dll инжектиться - типо panic режим

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Это в принципе невозможно. Единственное что можно делать это отдельный AppDomain и выгружать потом его, но в этом случае все вызовы нужно маршалить, что имеет перформанс кост.

Comment: Тем не менее, злонамеренный домен может защитить свой код от выгрузки: http://ideone.com/wecQQc

Comment: не только вызовы, но все типы, которые будут использоваться за пределами изолированного домена должны поддерживать маршалинг. Некоторые встроенные типы поддерживают если что, так что апеллировать к тому, что string или int работают и так, не надо, просто это уже предусмотрено.